# Second order homogeneous ordinary differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any hints on how to attack
$$
R''(r) + \frac{1}{r} R'(r) + a R(r) = 0
$$
where $a \equiv const.$?

Comment: The solution should contain Bessel functions of the first and second kind.

Comment: Bessel's equation requires $a=1$ how do I get around it?

Comment: Define a variable $x=\sqrt{a} r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered to a similar question :

$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dR}{dr}+cR=0 \tag{1}$$
Case $c>0$ :

Change of variable $x=\sqrt{c}\:r \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2R}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dR}{dx}+R=0$

This is the standard Bessel differential equation which general solution is :
$$R(x)=c_1J_0(x)+c_2Y_0(x)$$
Thus the solution of equation (1) is :
$$R(r)=c_1J_0(\sqrt{c}\:r)+c_2Y_0(\sqrt{c}\:r) $$
Bessel functions of first and second kind.

Case $c=0$ :
$$R(r)=c_1\ln|r|+c_2$$

Case $c<0$ :

Do the same with change of variable $x=\sqrt{-c}\:r$ which leads to
$$R(r)=c_1I_0(\sqrt{-c}\:r)+c_2K_0(\sqrt{-c}\:r) $$
Modified Bessel functions of first and second kind.